# Remove server.php from Laravel routes

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4

I just installed laravel following the instruction on Larvel docs. I chose to use install via composer create project command.

In the routes. php i created a dummy route

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return 'Front Page';
});
```

When i access `http://localhost/mysite/` It shows directory listing of mysite folder. However when i use `http://localhost/mysite/server.php` It runs my route closure.

I also tried alternate .htaccess code provided at Laravel's docs but that doesn't work either.

I want to remove the server.php from url.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: try going to `http://localhost/mysite/public/` you should see what you expect

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla but public folder isn't for assets ? How can i remove this public from the url ?

Comment: public folder is meant for assets and is also (supposed to be) the webservers root directory. If you are working on localhost that is not the case. In order to get rid of public you would have to change virtual host settings. Try this http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/25/creating-an-apache-virtualhost. The problem with doing virtual hosts is that other projects in localhost will become inaccessible.

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla so this is a normal behavious of laravel app? If it is so , Then i am fine with it ! What confuses me is at my workplace i don't see public folder in url in any app they created in Laravel.

Comment: Yes, this is normal and this is how laravel works. If you don't see public in the url it means that virualhosts have been properly configured for each laravel project.

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla can you post this as an answer so that i can close this question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is expected and this is how Laravel works. The `public` folder is meant for assets and is also (supposed to be) the webservers root directory.

If you are working on localhost that is not the case and the root directory contains multiple projects.

In order to get rid of public you would have to change virtual host settings. 
As mentioned here in the [site](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/25/creating-an-apache-virtualhost). 
The problem with doing virtual hosts is that other projects in localhost will become inaccessible.